# cp- copy a file in many folders, but only if it already exists there

Tags: terminal, bash

In another forum I saw this command:

> ls -1 | xargs -n 1 cp ../y/info.txt

It copies info.txt into sub folders (e.g. folder a, folder b, folder c) in the current working directory.

Now I want to copy the file info.txt to sub folders **replacing existing info.txt** files, but **do nothing when the sub folder doesn't contain info.txt**.

So I need the opposite of -n.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I had the command from: https://www.macuser.de/threads/cp-eine-datei-in-mehrere-ordner-kopieren.339641/page-2#post-9427370

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not parse the output of `ls`, use the `find` *command* instead:

```
find . -type f -name "info.txt" -exec cp -v ../y/info.txt {} \;
```

<sub>Note that the `-v` option with `cp` isn't necessary, I just like to see what's being copied where.</sub>

To address a comment, the `find` *command* shown above searches the entire `PWD`. If you want to limit the the search to just first level subdirectories of the `PWD` then add `-maxdepth 2` to the `find` *command*, e.g.:

```
find . -maxdepth 2 -type f -name "info.txt" -exec cp -v ../y/info.txt {} \;
```

In this scenario:

```
.
├── a
│   ├── 1
│   │   └── info.txt
│   └── info.txt
├── b
│   └── info.txt
└── c
```

Only `./a/info.txt` and `./b/info.txt` are replaced, `./a/1/info.txt` is not.

Comment: You probably need to limit the depth of the search, otherwise the copy will fail for subdirectories

Comment: @patrix, What!? If I understood the OP this does exactly what was asked as is, no need to limit find's depth as it's supposed to find all info.txt files in the subdirectories of the PWD.

Comment: Yeah, whatever. If the OP is happy, fine :-)

Comment: @patrix, I've updated my answer to address your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming somewhat sane directory names (no newlines etc.)

```
ls | while read dir; do
    [[ -e "$dir"/info.txt ]] && cp ../y/info.txt "$dir"/
done
```